# Can't enable CORS for web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I tried everything but can't enable CORS for my WebApi project. I guess I 'm missing something or not doing it right. 
My StartUp.config is:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            // Web API routes
            //app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableCors(new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.test.ca", "*", "GET,POST")); //enable only for this domain

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            app.UseWebApi(config);
            ConfigureAutofac(app, config);
        }
```

My api controller:

```
            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize]
            [Route("api/Accounts/GetTestTest")]
            [System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors("http://www.test.ca", "*", "*")]
            public HttpResponseMessage GetTestTest()
            {

                return this.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
```

Here I should be restricted because my request are made from MVC application which runs on localhost. Also I'm using tokens to authorize users.
Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT** Request is comming from MVC controller action like this:

```
static string CallApi(string url, string token, LogInRequest request)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                var t = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CashManager.Models.Global.Token>(token);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + t.access_token);
            }

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<string>(url,string.Empty).Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the requests coming from your C# backend in MVC or JavaScript in front-end?

Comment: Please see the edit. My request is comming from MVC controller which is using CallApi method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS does not apply to requests made from a back-end. It only applies to requests coming from browsers via AJAX.

You will need to do IP address-based filtering or something else to block requests from certain places. The authentication you have *might* be good enough though.